# problem in Non-ASCII character search in XML file using linq to XML

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, linq-to-xml, non-ascii-characters

I am serching for an element in an XML file using following linq to xml query

```
XElement inspections = XElement.Load(new StreamReader( Server.MapPath(ResolveUrl(SelectInspection.InspectionFilePath)),Encoding.UTF8));

XElement inspection = (from elements in inspections.Elements("inspection")
                                       where elements.Element("inspectionid").Value == inspectionId.ToString()
                                       && elements.Element("databasename").Value == Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Request.ContentEncoding.GetBytes (Request.QueryString("DbName")))
                                       select elements).Single();
```

And my xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inspections>
   <inspection>
    <inspectionid>8</inspectionid>
    <databasename>Åker</databasename>
    <exported>false</exported>
  </inspection>
 </inspections>
```

Despite the `Request.QueryString("DbName")` is equal to "Åker", query does not return any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a test web page with the following content:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <a href="WebForm1.aspx?DbName=Åker">Test</a><br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It's code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><inspections>   <inspection>    <inspectionid>8</inspectionid>    <databasename>Åker</databasename>    <exported>false</exported>  </inspection> </inspections>";
        var inspections = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
        XElement inspection = (from elements in inspections.Elements("inspection")
                               where elements.Element("databasename").Value == Request.QueryString["DbName"]
                               select elements).FirstOrDefault();
        lblTest.Text = (inspection != null).ToString();

    }
}
```

When I click `Test` link, the lblTest text becomes True — so, query finds the element as expected.

In addition to Jon Skeet's solution which probably fixes the problem, you may pass wrong `inspectionId` parameter value resulting in failed search.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the code you have posted. The query works fine for a string but not for a file. I tried following code in console and I get same error "Sequence contains no element" :



XElement inspections = XElement.Load(new StreamReader( "C:\\Test\\nonAscii.xml",Encoding.UTF8));

XElement inspection = (from elements in inspections.Elements("inspection")
            where 
             elements.Element("databasename").Value == "Åker"
            select elements).Single();

Comment: Sorry above code works correctly. I did not save the xml file(nonAscii.xml) in utf-8 encoding. I think request is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This looks wrong to me:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Request.ContentEncoding
                               .GetBytes(Request.QueryString("DbName")))
```

Why wouldn't `Request.QueryString` already have had appropriate decoding applied by ASP.NET?

I suggest you split the problem into two halves:

- Make sure LINQ to XML can find the string: do that in a console app with hard-coded data
- Make sure you can get the right query string: do that by logging the Unicode codepoints within `Request.QueryString("DbName")` as integers

I would *expect* you to just be able to use `Request.QueryString("DbName")` directly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I just added those encoding to be sure nothing is wrong. It was previously as you have written. I checked the Xml file is saved with utf-8 encodinf. to be sure not any editor saved the data using another encoding, and my globalization key (requestEncoding) is set to utf-8. Encoding conversion in the example just added to fix any possible problem. I tried to run the query on a string, it works fine. but not on the file.

Comment: @Ehsan: I suggest you dump the Unicode code points (as integers) of the value when loaded from a file.